# Declaring array with user-defined size before the main function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a an array `int matrix[10][10]` as well as other arrays with similar size which is declared before the prototype functions and main function. This 2d array is used by all of the functions. However, I need my program to have a function that asks the user the size of the matrix he wants. So, it's gotta be something like this: `int matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS]`. I know for sure that I can't place the declare the array inside the main function since this array is used by all the other functions. How do I declare this kind of array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: Declaration, definition and initialization are three different things.
You can declare and define the array in the global scope yet initialize it in main

Comment: You cannot declare a array like that if the dimensions are not compile-time constants, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c

Comment: Any reason not to use [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is impossible to declare an [array with variable sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c), as they are not legal in C++ (although they are legal in C). So you're out of luck here.
Second, you want the declaration before `main`. Hence, you have to use either

1. A dynamic array, defined globally like `int** matrix;` and initialized in `main()` as

   ```
   matrix = new int*[ROWS];
   for(size_t i = 0 ; i < ROWS; ++i)
       matrix[i] = new int[COLS];
   ```

   then you'd have to release its memory at the end of the day

   ```
   for(size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
       delete[] matrix[i];
   delete[] matrix;
   ```

or

2. A standard container like [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

   ```
   std::vector<int> matrix; // defined globally
   ```

and in `main()` reserve memory for it, like

```
matrix.reserve(ROWS*COLUMNS); // reserve memory for M rows
```

Then you'd need to play around with the indexes, so you can map from pairs of indexes to 1D index, i.e. the "logical" element `[i][j]` is represented by the index `i * COLS + j` in `matrix`.

Of course, you could have used a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, however this approach is faster since the memory is guaranteed to be contiguous (same applies to the first example, where you could have used an `int*` instead).